# GoToStateAction cannot see my states in Blend

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

I have my visual states defined in UserControl.Resources. This is the sample :-

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AlbumDetailsStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3">
                        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                            <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="HideState"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="ShowState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="250" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.TextWrapping)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <TextWrapping>NoWrap</TextWrapping>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
            <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
```

Now i want to change the states from within my `itemtemplate` of `listbox`. I am using `GoToStateAction` behavior of Blend. However it is not able to find my states. But if i try to change states from outside itemtemplate it is available. It is so annoying. How do i workaround this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the visual states as part of your root layout container instead of in the resources section?